# How to avoid MediaScanner delete database entries?

Tags: android

in Android the system does not scan flac lossless audio files, so I write a scanner to scan them, put into Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, and it works well - until the MediaScanner activates and delete the entries I have inserted.
Is there a way to prevent MediaScanner deletes them, or some trick to know when MediaScanner is done, so I can call my scanner up to scan and insert again?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the MediaScanner is done scanning your sd card by adding BroadcastReceiver to your code which handles ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER. For the sample code, you can refer to the link below.

[Initialize MediaScanner at Beginning of Android Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520142/initialize-mediascanner-at-beginning-of-android-program/7643140#7643140)

With regards to FLAC file not being recognized by MediaScanner, you need to add the file's mimetype and extension to the /android/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaFile.java.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that something is null? I remember that I tried to insert null once and everything was deleted?