# Initialize MediaScanner at Beginning of Android Program

Tags: android

I have an Android program that starts off by loading some of the user's media. Occasionally the program crashes -- both on an emulator and on an actual phone. I've found this is because sometimes media only become available to the program after the activity has been running for a while.

When this happens, here is the order of the typical log output:

1. DEBUG/MediaScanner(166): opendir /system/media/ failed, errno: 2    <--PROGRAM ERROR HERE
2. DEBUG/MediaScannerService(166): done scanning volume internal
3. DEBUG/MediaScannerService(166): start scanning volume external
4. VERBOSE/MediaProvider(166): /sdcard volume ID: 45454545
5. VERBOSE/MediaProvider(166): Attached volume: external
6. DEBUG/MediaScannerService(166): done scanning volume external  <-- THIS IS IN MIDDLE OF PROGRAM

The program has an error at #1 because it tried to load media that wasn't available until #6.

Is there any way to force Android to finish the MediaScannerService at the beginning of the program?

Alternatively, is there any way to check when the MediaScannerService has finished scanning?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a **BroadcastReceiver** in your code and handle **ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED** broadcast. It is actually being sent by MediaScannerService once it's done scanning. Hope the sample code below helps.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED);
filter.addDataScheme("file");
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);   

BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED)) {
                Toast.makeText(MediaScannerActivity.this, "Scan complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
```